# Zoom Konva to center of visible area

Tags: canvas, coordinates, zooming, konvajs

Konva.js is used to implement zoomable whiteboard, but I'm struggling to implement that and object in the visible area would stay in the center of the area while zooming.
So, here is an example:

Picture with 100% and not changed position ("red 1" drawn is approximately in the center):
[image]

Then stage is scaled by 0.25 – "red 1" stays in the area center:
[image]

If scale is back to 1, and we move position for "green 2" to be in the area center:
[image]

And then scale stage by 0.25 – "green 2" goes to the right of the area (and "red 1" continues to stay at approximately the same place):
[image]

The function used to implement zooming is as next:

```
const zoom = (isZoomIn) => {
  const scaleToSet = getScale(isZoomIn)

  const width = konvaStage.current.width()
  const height = konvaStage.current.height()
  const x = konvaStage.current.x()
  const y = konvaStage.current.y()

  const deltaScale = scalePrev - scaleToSet
  const deltaVisibleWidth = width * deltaScale
  const deltaVisibleHeight = height * deltaScale

  const newPosition = {
    x: x + deltaVisibleWidth / 2,
    y: y + deltaVisibleHeight / 2
  }

  konvaStage.current.setAttrs({
    position: newPosition,
    scale: { x: scaleToSet, y: scaleToSet }
  })
}
```

How the above function may be adjusted for any object in the center of visible area would stay in the center after stage is scaled (in given example "2 green" on the last page should be in the center of the area)?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Thanks for your help. And yeah, I saw this example before, and it helped to resolve the task which stayed initially, but it does not answer the question above...

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

It is not absolutely clear but it seems your question is about scaling with a specified object as the zoom point. Like perhaps when a specific object has 'focus' in your app.

I think what you need is to scale from an arbitrary point on the canvas.

There is an example of scaling from the mouse position in the Konva documentation at https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Zooming_Relative_To_Pointer.html. This could easily be adopted by changing the mouse position for some other point.  See the line

`var pointer = stage.getPointerPosition();`

Replace this by

`var pointer = {x: <your x position>, y: <your y position>};`

For any shape you can use the getClientRect() function, and using the centre point of the shape would give viable x & y for the above.

The scaling function from the Konva docs example is included as a working snippet here in case the link changes.

Run the snippet and use your mouse wheel to zoom in & out anywhere on the canvas - note that the canvas is smoothly scaled from the mouse position. Though this question & answer relate to the Konva canvas library, the technique is applicable to any 2D drawing zoom process.

```js
      var width = window.innerWidth;
      var height = window.innerHeight;

      var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height,
      });

      var layer = new Konva.Layer();
      stage.add(layer);

      var circle = new Konva.Circle({
        x: stage.width() / 2,
        y: stage.height() / 2,
        radius: 50,
        fill: 'green',
      });
      layer.add(circle);

      var scaleBy = 1.01;
      stage.on('wheel', (e) => {
        e.evt.preventDefault();
        var oldScale = stage.scaleX();

        var pointer = stage.getPointerPosition();

        var mousePointTo = {
          x: (pointer.x - stage.x()) / oldScale,
          y: (pointer.y - stage.y()) / oldScale,
        };

        var newScale =
          e.evt.deltaY > 0 ? oldScale * scaleBy : oldScale / scaleBy;

        stage.scale({ x: newScale, y: newScale });

        var newPos = {
          x: pointer.x - mousePointTo.x * newScale,
          y: pointer.y - mousePointTo.y * newScale,
        };
        stage.position(newPos);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8.2.1/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```